# MongoDB Aggregation returning empty object instead of null

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I am currently having issues with my aggregation
The problem is, the 'rank' field is returning an empty object if the rank is null or does not exist. I want it to return null, not an empty object.

```js
const query = await this.db.collection('users').aggregate([
    { $match: { ...filter } },
    { $lookup: { from: 'ranks', localField: 'rank', foreignField: '_id', as: 'rank' } },
    { $unwind: { path: '$rank', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $project: this.getProjectionFields(fields) }
]).toArray();
```

[image]

*Changing `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: false` will not return the document at all.*
Is there a way to resolve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do your dataset(s) look like? Can you provide a snippet from the `users` collection, as well as from the `ranks` collection (or just supply us with a snippet of the data from the `$lookup` step in your query).. This may be a mongoose bug, [from testing this in Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BsfWgmBTvCD) I am seeing expected results.

Comment: Also, from looking around on the web, it seems like most queries `$unwind` before `$lookup`.. I wonder if you swap them, if it will work? [This is one of the examples I found of this online](https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-to-preserve-Null-and-Empty-array-response-during-unwind/)

Comment: That just returns an empty array.

Comment: What makes you think it will return `null`? From their [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#unwind-preservenullandemptyarrays) it seems like `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` does not behave as you think it does. If it is `true`, and the path is specifically `null` or does not exist, the document is still returned (which is what you're seeing when the `$unwind` is before `$lookup`).. I believe having `$lookup` before `$unwind` is what causes 'rank' to be an empty object (obviously the order has something to do with it)..

Comment: It would be really helpful if you supplied a snippet of each collection (can be fake values, its the structure that really matters)... It's hard to tell whats going on without seeing the underlying data, since that plays a key role in this.

Comment: @user12869402 : What do you've in here :: `this.getProjectionFields(fields)` that might be causing an issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `$cond` inside the `$project` stage which will evaluate if `rank` is empty object, return null, else return the value of that field.

```
// create project stage to return null if field is an empty object
  $project: {
    ...projectOtherUserFields,
    rank: {
      $cond: { if: { $eq: ['$rank', {}] }, then: null, else: '$rank' }
    }
  }
```

See if that works for you.